# Cassandra cluster old data is not replicated in new node

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0, cql3, cqlsh

I installed apache cassandra on my local system for testing purpose. With 1 system (1 node) i was able to read/write and query in the database. I added another node and created a cluster. Now the data that I write on my system is replicated on other node and vice versa, but the data which was present on my system earlier to the addition of new node is not replicated. Though the Keyspaces and Tables are present on new node but they are empty. Did I do something wrong while adding the new node to the cluster?

Comment: Is the new node in a different data center?

Comment: Nope its in the same data center. I have used SimpleStrategy as replication strategy. After adding the node in cluster whatever write is done is visible on the other node but the data prior to adding new node is not present even though the keyspace and tables are present.

Comment: Okay, based on that, my answer is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that you have auto_bootstrap turned off (it is ON by default). From the documentation:

> auto_bootstrap
>       (Default: true ) This setting has been removed from default configuration. It makes new (non-seed) nodes automatically migrate the right data to themselves. When initializing a fresh cluster with no data, add auto_bootstrap: false.

The easiest way to fix this is to run a repair on the node which will ensure that it gets any data it's missing.

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_repair_nodes_c.html

Comment: I could not find auto_bootstrap option in Cassandra.yaml file. Maybe it has been removed from the configuration files in latest versions. I found out that due to auto_bootstrap off by default the data was not replicated. I ran the repair command on the new node which replicated all the data which was missing. Thanks for your help. Cheers :)

Comment: Yes, that's right. The option  has been removed in recent versions but you can add it back in if you need it for future nodes.

Comment: Yes. Hey mildewey I was trying something with sstableloader can you help me with that? I am able to load SStables in my cluster and on independent nodes too. Now I want to add different SSTables(i.e. different data) in different nodes of a cluster using a single sstableloader command or we can say simultaneously, actually to check the speed am able to get while doing so. Is there a way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't done much with sstableloader, but the community here on SO is usually pretty responsive.

Comment: Note that your first sentence says that auto_bootstrap is OFF by default. It seems to be that if the default is *true* then it is ON by default, wouldn't you say?

Answer (score 0):

Simply run this on new node if the data on it is not up-to-date.

Run $CASSANDRA_HOME/bin/nodetool rebuild

Login as cqlsh and verify that new node has received the data.

Also look into below -

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_add_dc_to_cluster_t.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have correct seeds and replication settings. But still the data is not getting replicated to new data center. Please perform `nodetool repair` with `-full` option will replicate data to the new datacenter node.